# Applying partially applied template

Tags: c++, templates

Having a class like the A, is there a way to apply it to a template like this of B, with T2 set to some type C? But without creating another template class inheriting from A.

```c
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{ };

template<template <typename T1> class T3>
class B
{ };
```

Comment: So there is no good solution for C++<11? I am wondering, what has stopped people from resigning the madness of this #$%^@# language, before 11. -_-

Comment: There is no other solution, that's why we have and use C++11 now :)

Comment: Yeah, 20 years of dealing with hundreds of problems eventually brought some solutions. And they will be fully implemented in compilers after only another 10. -- The laziness the standardization guys should bring this language to its grave long time ago.

Comment: While this is not the place for a discussion, I just add this one comment: I prefer things to go slowly as it's much easier to break a language by adding every little "feature" that the users ask for. In 20 years I've seen languages and technologies come and go, but C++ is still here and IMHO stronger than ever.

Comment: I am aware of those claims. But I'm quite convinced, they are false. 20 years is not a proper time to think though and solve such problems as the above. Not saying, that this should be solved at the very beginning of the templates. During preview analysis of the concept, this is something which easily comes to your eyes. -- Sorry for the discussion not in the place, but I have little of options to reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will propose an alternative solution: *do not use* template template parameters.

If you write:

```
template <typename T> struct B {};
```

Then it can be used with `A<int, int>` or `C<3>` or even plain `D`.

Whilst it is possible to use template template parameters, it is general a bad idea. You should treat the template parameter of a class *as an implementation detail* and apply the golden rule: do not rely on implementation details.

If you need access to the type, somehow, then use an *associated type* (aka `T::AssociatedType`) or a *trait* (`BTraits<T>::AssociatedType`).

**EDIT:** dealing with multiple instantiations of the template template parameter.

Suppose we want to "erase" the template template parameter of such a class:

```
template <template <typename> class A>
struct Something {
    template <typename T>
    void doit() { A<T>::doit(); }
};
```

The C++ standard allocation model is to use an inner `rebind` structure:

```
template <typename T>
struct Simple {
    template <typename U>
    struct rebind { typedef Simple<U> type; };
};

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct Multi {
    template <typename U>
    struct rebind { typedef Multi<U, T1> type; };
};

template <typename A>
struct Something {
    template <typename T>
    void doit() { typedef typename A::rebind<T>::type B; B::doit(); }
};
```

*Note how you can use complex computations in `rebind` and nothing forces you in blindly passing the type received as parameter.*

Whilst another (similar) solution is to ask for a factory (aka, the object passed itself cannot be used but it can build useful objects); for ease of use the C++ containers ask of their allocators that they be both usable in themselves and factories for other types.

Comment: Actually T1 is provided by the class B in my case. -- And yes, it is desired to the parameter was an implementation detail. B class is in fact a memory manager and I want for it a possibility to use different memory allocation strategies. But I am quite not interested in passing those strategies during run-time. -- I deeply care about each single instruction, so I want to pass statically whatever I can.

Comment: @Number47: I see, I edited my answer to provide the `rebind` trick that the STL uses to switch from `std::allocator<int>` to `std::allocator<_ListNode<int>>` internally (for example).

Answer (score 3):

With C++11 using a template alias works:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{ };

template<template <typename T1> class T3>
class B
{ };

class C
{ };

template< typename T > using A1 = A< T, C >;

int main()
{
    B< A1 > b;
}
```

without C++11, you are left with what you probably already know:

```
template< typename T > class A1 : A< T, C > {};
```

Comment: And I only need to forward all constructors each time I give another C type. Great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using C++11's alias template:

```
template <typename T>
using AA = A<T, C>;

B<AA> b;
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/pWZrVz)